# Reemplazar caracteres

Tags: html, jquery, datatables

Puede que este post parezca duplicado, pero he probado varias formas y no se me soluciona el problema.

Tengo un DataTable en el que cargo dinámicamente etiquetas HTML.

Estas etiquetas, en vez de estar así:

```
<img src="ruta" />
```

están así:

```
&lt;img  src="ruta"/&gt;
```

Me he hecho un script en jquery que me reemplace los caracteres `&lt;` y `&gt;` por `<` y `>` respectivamente.

El problema es que solo me sustituye la primera aparición, quedando un mensaje así:

```
 <img  src="ruta"/> &lt;img  src="ruta"/&gt; &lt;img  src="ruta"/&gt; &lt;img  src="ruta"/&gt;
```

Mi código **Jquery** es el siguiente

```
$(".message").each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var t = $this[0].innerHTML;
            $this.html(t.replace('&lt;','<').replace('&gt;', '>'));
        });
```

Mi **HTML** está así:

```
<div class="message">&lt;img  src="ruta"/&gt; &lt;img  src="ruta"/&gt; </div>
```

Ese div es parte de un row de un datatable.

¿Cómo podría hacer que Datatable renderice las etiquetas HTML o que JQUERY sustituya los caracteres de TODOS los mensajes en vez de solo el primero.

Gracias.

Comment: No había encontrado esa pregunta, pues sí, parece que ahí también lo solucionan!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo tienes casi hecho, lo que te faltaba era usar una expresión regular con el modificador global (`g`)

```js
const original='&lt;img  src="ruta"/&gt; &lt;img  src="ruta"/&gt; ';

const cambiado=original.replace(/&lt;/g,'<').replace(/&gt;/g,'>');
console.log(cambiado)
```

Pequeña explicación: El método `replace` admite como primer parámetro un string **provocando la sustitución de la primera coincidencia** o una expresión regular. En el caso de la expresión regular, puedes definir ciertos modificadores.

Aqui tienes un ejemplo:

```js
const miExpReg= /a/gi;

console.log('Aquí hay letras mAyúsculas y minúsculas'.replace(miExpReg,'_'));
```

g -> **global** (*todas las coincidencias*)
i -> ignora **mayúsculas/minúsculas**

Comment: Gracias! no había caído en usar expresiones regulares :)